# How to deserialize JSON in vb.net when the JSON is an array(?)

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string in vb.net. The problem I'm having is (I think) because the string is an array of JSON objects as opposed to a single JSON object (in all honesty this is a bit of a guess). I think this because the file starts with [ and ends with ] and between each pair of {} there is a comma.

Here's a link to the data I'm trying to work with:

[data link](https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=53.044915764206,-0.925366163226158:53.044915764206,-1.07463383677384:52.955084235794,-1.07463383677384:52.955084235794,-0.925366163226158&date=2018-1)

I'll include the first few lines at the bottom of the question for reference (it's a bit long to include in it's entirety). I'm using Newtonsoft to parse the string but it isn't working:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

...
        Dim json As String = getCrimeData(area)
        Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList
        Dim output As String = ""
        For Each item As JProperty In data
            item.CreateReader()
            Select Case item.Name

            End Select
        Next
```

No idea why it's not working the error message I get is:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 289.'
```

For reference here is the first few lines:

```
[{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"52.961180","street":{"id":1066985,"name":"On or near Deabill Street"},"longitude":"-1.072366"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62066811,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"52.989060","street":{"id":1061254,"name":"On or near Park\/open Space"},"longitude":"-0.988926"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62065597,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"52.958492","street":{"id":1067012,"name":"On or near Mallard Road"},"longitude":"-1.064310"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62066947,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"52.964901","street":{"id":1066875,"name":"On or near Asper Street"},"longitude":"-1.072257"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62065125,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"53.010153","street":{"id":1070264,"name":"On or near Old Tannery Drive"},"longitude":"-0.997808"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62065476,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"52.987829","street":{"id":1068825,"name":"On or near Supermarket"},"longitude":"-1.036609"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62065402,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},
```

Comment: You arent deserializing at all - you are parsing it.  If you need more than just a few things, you probably want to Deserialize

Comment: You could try to copy the JSON, then in VS go to Edit , Paste Special, and Past JSON as classes to generate the structure needed to capture. then use the json library to deserialize into the structure.

Comment: @Jeremy I've got as far as making the JSON classes, how do I go about deserliazing to them?

Comment: Assuming you have the correct classes: `Dim crimes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ROOTOBJECT))(jstr)`  where `ROOTOBJECT` is whaterver you named it